Verifying signed message with Qt's QCA::SecureMessage
I want to write a Qt application that reads a signed message and verifies its signature through QCA::SecureMessage. Using QCA's examples page and reading their unit tests from the publicly available repository, I came up with the following code:
bool verifyMessage(const QString& messagePath, const QString& pubKeyPath){
    // ... Checking that files exist and can be opened
    QFile messageFile(messagePath);
    messageFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    
    // Initialize QCA and store manager
    QCA::Initializer init;
    QCA::KeyStoreManager::start();
    QCA::KeyStoreManager keyStoreManager(this);
    keyStoreManager.waitForBusyFinished();

    // qDebug() << keyStoreManager.keyStores(); // this yields 2 existing stores, ("qca-softstore", "qca-default-systemstore"), both valid and readOnly

    QCA::KeyStore pgpStore(QStringLiteral("qca-default-systemstore"), &keyStoreManager);
    QCA::ConvertResult convResult;
    QCA::PGPKey publicPGPKey = QCA::PGPKey::fromFile(pubKeyPath, &convResult);
    if (convResult != QCA::ConvertGood || publicPGPKey.isNull()) {
        qCWarning(DroneActivationLog) << "Failed to load public key";
        return false;
    }
    // pgpStore.writeEntry(publicPGPKey); // This fails because the store is readonly
    QByteArray signedData = messageFile.readAll(); // messageFile contains the whole signed message, signature is not detached
    
    // Initializing pgp and message
    QCA::OpenPGP pgp;
    QCA::SecureMessageKey key;
    QCA::SecureMessage message(&pgp);
    key.setPGPPublicKey(publicPGPKey);

    message.setRecipient(key); // I suspect this is wrong
    message.setFormat(QCA::SecureMessage::Format::Ascii);
    message.startVerify();
    message.update(signedData);
    message.end();
    message.waitForFinished();

    if (message.verifySuccess()) {
        qDebug() << "VERIFICATION SUCCESS" << message.read();
        return true;
    }
    qDebug() << "VERIFICATION ERROR\n" << message.diagnosticText();
    return false;
}

Although I verified that the message and the key are read correctly from the file, this code always fail the verification with error
VERIFICATION ERROR
"GPGProc: Pipe setup completeGPGProc: Running: [/usr/bin/gpg --no-tty --pinentry-mode loopback --enable-special-filenames --status-fd 16 --command-fd 13 --armor --decrypt]GPGProc: Process started{PLAINTEXT 75 1728306273 }{PLAINTEXT_LENGTH 11}{NEWSIG}{ERRSIG F092BE69AD20348E 1 10 00 1728306273 9 -}{NO_PUBKEY F092BE69AD20348E}GPGProc: Process finished: 2GPGProc: DoneGPG Process Finished: exitStatus=2stderr: [gpg: Signature made Mon 07 Oct 2024 01:04:33 PM UTC
gpg:                using RSA key F092BE69AD20348E
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
]GpgAction error: ErrorUnknown
wasSigned: verifyResult: VerifyNoKey"

My interpretation is that the public key is not being actually used, and it needs to be imported.  In fact, if I manually import the key from the shell, executing
gpg --import pubKey.asc
before executing my application, then it works, as the key is found in the system's readOnly keystore. When I ship this code, though, I will not have access to a command line on the executing machine.
Can I programmatically import the public key into an existing KeyStore? Or should I create my own KeyStore, since the 2 existing ones are both readOnly? In that case, how do I add it to the KeyStoreManager, which appears to have no such method from its documentation?
More in general: is this a sane way to go about sending a signed file to a device where my Qt based application can read and verify it knowing only the sender's public key or is there an easier method?

message.setRecipient() is definitely wrong, because that method is used when you want to create a message and then decide who to encrypt the message to. You can try message.setSigner(), but the API docs of QCA say that this is for CMS messages, and doesn't mention OpenPGP at all. If that doesn't work, then it appears that QCA's OpenPGP support only works for verifying signatures that have a public key in the local GnuPG key store.

I tried both, but that does not work. setSigner() is used when signing a message.
QCA::KeyStore do have a writeEntry() method that can take a PGPKey as input, but that only works on KeyStores that aren't readOnly. I guess what I'm asking then is if it's possible to access and manipulate the local GnuPG KeyStore programmatically

As far as I can tell from the QCA API, it doesn't appear to support what you want to do. That said: I believe QCA's OpenPGP support was added mainly to integrate with GnuPG (for e.g. OpenPGP support in email programs using the user's key store), so it might not be the right tool for you. There are plenty of other OpenPGP implementations for C++, have you tried any of these?

I have not, because the PGP requirement is not strict. I would prefer sticking to QCA, so I will try to achieve verification of a signed file using QCA::PublicKey and its verifyMessage() method

As crhis_se points out in the comments, QCA apparently does not support this specific use case.
In order to solve the problem of verifying a signed file, I ended up going for a different solution using QCA::PublicKey to read a RSA public key and verify the message:
bool verifyMessage(const QString& pubKeyPath, const QString& messagePath, const QString& signaturePath){
    // ... Checking that files exist
    QFile messageFile(messagePath);
    messageFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QFile signatureFile(signaturePath);
    signatureFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    
    // Initialize QCA
    QCA::Initializer init;
    QCA::ConvertResult convResult;
    QCA::PublicKey publicKey = QCA::RSAPublicKey::fromPEMFile(pubKeyPath, &convResult);
    if (convResult != QCA::ConvertGood) {
        qCWarning(DroneActivationLog) << "Could not read public key";
        return;
    }

    QCA::MemoryRegion fileRegion(messageFile.readAll()); // Depending on the format, trimmed() might be necessary to remove the EOF character.

    return publicKey.verifyMessage(fileRegion, signatureFile.readAll(), QCA::EMSA3_SHA256);
}

The disadvantage here is that now the signature is detached, i.e. it exists in a separate file, but at least the message can be verified.
